# p5.js: Add filter to uploaded image

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js, imagefilter

I want to add gray filter to the uploaded image.But using img.filter(GRAY,0.3) do not work. I know img is an p5 element here,is there any way to select the image source only and add filter to the uploaded image?

```js
var img,canvas;

function setup(){
    var uploadBtn = createFileInput(imageUpload);
    canvas=createCanvas(500,400);
}
function imageUpload(file){
    img = loadImage(file.data,function(){
        image(img,0,0,width,height);
        img.filter(GRAY,0.5);
    })
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases/download/0.5.7/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.7/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you apply the filter after displaying the image.When `imageUpload()` function is called, and `image(img,0,0,width,height);` is executed, the `img` image is displayed on the page, however that's **static**, it does not update like it would if it was in **`draw()`** and hence applying the image filter after displaying the image does not change anything (The image doesn't update because it's static). If you wrote the exact same code in `draw()` it would work because that gets called repeatedly. To fix this simply apply the grey filter before displaying the image :

```js
var img,canvas;

function setup(){
    var uploadBtn = createFileInput(imageUpload);
    canvas=createCanvas(500,400);
}
function imageUpload(file){
    img = loadImage(file.data,function(){
        img.filter(GRAY,0.5);
        image(img,0,0,width,height);            
    })        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases/download/0.5.7/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.7/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would reword your answer slightly: it's not because `imageUpload()` is only called once. It's because OP is applying the filter after the image is drawn. Otherwise this is the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that also, my point of saying that was to contrast it with `draw()`  which gets called repeatedly, so what the OP wrote will actually work in `draw()`, i'll edit my post to make it clear, thanks!

Comment: Adding only filter after image also worked http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/filter  -                                                                     image(img,0,0,width,height);                                                                                      filter(THRESHOLD,0.5)                                                                                          Thanks for your answer.